# Loop should be simplified by calling Select - sonar cloud error c#

Tags: c#, .net, sonarcloud

I get `SonarCloud` error in this code:

```
foreach (var item in itemList)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name))
    {
        throw new BadRequestException("Item name is null or missing...");
    }
    if (someOtherList.Any(x => x.Name == item.Name))
    {
        throw new NotAcceptedException("Item name already exist in Db.");
    }
}
```

My question is how to translate this code into `LINQ` using `Select` (as sonar suggest) when I have `exceptions`?

Comment: Which line of code Sonar is complaining about?

Comment: In the first line, it underlines the itemList.

Comment: What's the type of the itemList. List or IEnumerable?

Comment: I think might be a false positive, this code shouldn't be converted to a select expression.

Comment: @fbede I am thinking the same... It can be done, but it will be ugly in my opinion. :)

Answer (score 9):

I found the solution in order for sonar to be happy. :) But honestly it makes sense.

So, sometimes you can get the this error when you want to iterate through whole object but you just need one property, like in this situation. Here I want to iterate only through the names, so the solution will be:

```
foreach (var itemName in itemList.Select(x => x.Name))
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemName))
    {
        throw new BadRequestException("Item name is null or missing...");
    }
    if (someOtherList.Any(x => x.Name == itemName))
    {
        throw new NotAcceptedException("Item name already exist in Db.");
    }
}
```